# reading a local variable as an Object property

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to define a new Object type named attributes from an external config file, however I am not sure how to read the property dynamically as even without apostrophes it is being read as a string.

```
var dynAtt1 =  vl.popupAttributes.att1 ;
  


    var attributes = new Object({
        dynAtt1 : { title: dynAtt1 }

    })
```

`dynAtt1` is being read literally instead of what it is defined as in the config.

Comment: *"dynAtt1 is being read literally"* - Your second line of code has two instances of that symbol, which one are you talking about?  Can you provide a more complete runnable example with observable output and indicate how that output differs from what you expect?

Comment: How about `attributes[dynAtt1] = { title: dynAtt1 };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a computed property name.

```
var attributes = {
  [dynAtt1] : { title: dynAtt1 }
}
```